# Rounding to the nearest half (NOT the nearest whole)

Tags: java, double, rounding

I need to round a double to the nearest .5. I *do not* want to end up with a number ending in .0.

I've searched around for a bit, but it seems like everyone wants to round to the nearest *multiple* of .5 rather than just the nearest half but not whole. I tried dividing by .5, rounding that, and multiplying by .5, but this still rounds to multiples of .5. Adding or subtracting .5 after this will not always round the number where it should go (you might add when you should have subtracted).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Ah, forgot to write that. Java.

Comment: For me floor function, than adding 0.5 solves your issue.

Comment: What about 3.6, for example? It should go to 3.5, but now turns out to be 4.0.

Comment: @user2431245: Using @cerkiewny's solution? It works for me: `Math.floor(3.6) + 0.5 == 3.5`

Comment: @Craig: but Math.floor(3.1) + 0.5 = 3.5 instead of 3.0

Comment: This is actually a very useful rounding approach for intermediate values, because it allows you to round to fewer significant bits without having to do an addition operation.  The "half" can be considered an implied bit that is always 1 and thus not significant or requiring extra computation in many cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Subtract, round and add...

```
Math.round(value - 0.5) + 0.5
```

Another working way mentioned in question's comments:

```
Math.floor(value) + 0.5
```

Comment: It is wrong round algorithm. Math.floor(3.1) + 0.5 will give you 3.5 instead of 3.

Comment: Exactly what he asked for.

Comment: unfortunately correct ^

Answer (score 17):

I think that `Math.round(num * 2) / 2.0f` should solve the rounding to the nearest half problem:

```
Math.round(3.9 * 2) / 2.0f == 8 / 2.0f = 4.0
Math.round(3.6 * 2) / 2.0f == 7 / 2.0f = 3.5
Math.round(3.1 * 2) / 2.0f == 6 / 2.0f = 3.0
```

Comment: **The only correct answer here.**

Answer (score 3):

rounding to any fraction f:

```
double f = 0.5;
double rounded = f * Math.round(x/f);
```

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned that in the question. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for whole numbers.

Comment: what is a whole number in your case? Do you mean integer?