# Rounding nearest to (1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 etc..) javascript

Tags: javascript, rounding

To clarify, the problem is how to round a number like this. i.e. 1.512 should round to 1.5 and 2.123 should round to 2 and 2.323 should round to 2.5 (javascript)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17998232/893780), although meant for Java, works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[1.512, 2.123, 2.323].forEach(function(currentNumber){
    console.log(Math.round(currentNumber * 2) / 2);
});
```

**Output**

```
1.5
2
2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var num = 1.222;
 num = num.toFixed(1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Math.round(x) function for rounding to nearest integer value